# If $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ matrices such that $A^{2} B^{2} = 0$ then

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices such that $A^{2} B^{2} = 0$ then which of the following is true?

a) $B^{2} A^{2} = 0$

b)   $AB = 0$

c)   Either $A^{2} =0$ or $B^{2} = 0$.

d)   Either $A$ or $B$ has zero determinant.

My current reasoning:
$$A^{2} B^{2} = 0. $$
So, 
$$\det(A^{2}B^{2}) = 0$$
$$\det(A^{2}) \det(B^{2}) = 0.$$
       So from here either $A^{2}$ or $B^{2}$ is singular.

Also 
$$\det(A^{2} B^{2}) = \det(A)\det(AB)\det(B)$$

So, either $A$ or $AB$ or $B$ is singular.

I'm confused. I could only do this so far. 
Option c is incorrect as finding counter example for c was easy.
Is there any other way to find solution without using counter examples for incorrect options.

Comment: I am curious about your counterexample to d.

Comment: Sorry, it was for c

Answer (score 1):

Just go a little bit further, along the lines you've already described:

$$0=\det (A^2B^2) = \det(A)\det(AB)\det(B) = \det(A)\det(A)\det(B)\det(B).$$
If a product of several real numbers is zero, what can you conclude about those numbers?

That's enough to answer the multiple-choice question, though for your own learning, you should *also* reason through claims a--c and prove or disprove them.

Comment: Option d is correct. Option b and c are incorrect by counterexamples. How can I prove option a incorrect$?$

Answer (score 1):

$$\det(A^{2} B^{2}) = \det(A)\det(A)\det (B)\det(B)=0 \iff \det A =0 \text { or} \det B =0$$

Thus the correct answer is (d)

Comment: Yes, but I need to disprove option a. Can you give any hint for option a$?$

Comment: (d) is the correct answer, why are you worried about (a)?

Comment: I couldn't find any counter example for a. If this question were of multiple select type, then I would need to disprove option a.

Comment: @Mathsaddict Let $A$ be an orthogonal projection and $B$ be an oblique projection that project onto orthogonal subspaces.

Comment: @eyeballfrog thanks, I think I should study orthogonal and obliqe projection.